# Screen resolution problem in Fedora 17 on Oracle VirtualBox 4.2

Tags: linux, fedora, virtualbox, resolution

I have HP Pavilion dv6 6119tx system which has a screen resolution of 1366X768. But after installing fedora 17 on VirtualBox with Guest additions, the default resolution is 1280X768. Whenever I switch to fullscreen mode, I have some black space left on both left and right sides of screen. Please help.

Please also suggest me some resources to learn basics of Linux, commands in Linux(specifically Fedora 17).

Answer (score 6):

For documentation, Fedora has a pretty good for basics: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/index.html

Now regarding your problem I had the same issue and to avoid it I've performed the following as root:

```
[root@testmachine ~]# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 32000 x 32000
VBOX0 connected 1600x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200      60.0*+
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

This will provide all the available modes. To add a new one perform the following:

```
    [root@testmachine ~]# cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Let's create a new mode for XRAND and associate it to the screen.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VBOX0 1920x1080_60.00
```

And now it's time to activate the output

```
xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

the VBOX0 value you get from the first xrandr command to see your display id.
Change the cvt value and update the commands accordingly to match your cvt output.

Comment: This worked for me: +1. :-) But how can this be made permanent? I asked the [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111758/how-to-set-up-screen-resolution-permanently) yesterday but it didn't seem to get much grip. Maybe you could take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with Fedora 19 guest on Windows 7 64 bit host, VirtualBox 4.2.18, and my research brought me here.  After additional research, I found that guest additions had not been **properly** installed.  Once I followed the instructions at

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15679#

the clipboard worked correctly.  The simple "install guest additions" from the Devices menu does not get all of the prerequisites for *some* of the features.

Answer (score 0):

- Settings->Video-> Video Memory = 128 MB, Enable 3D acceleration = true.
- Install GuestAdditions
- On Host machine, in cmd/bash, run

> VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any

- create /etc/X11/xorg.conf file with content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier      "Configured Video Device" 
EndSection
Section "Monitor" 
  Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection 
Section "Screen"  
  Identifier      "Default Screen" 
  Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
  Device          "Configured Video Device" 
  SubSection "Display"
    Modes "1366x768" 
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

- For running VM: Hostkey(Right Ctrl at default) +Home - view - full Screen

I have tried to exclude every step except GuestAdditions installation. You need every one of them.