# How to set up screen resolution permanently

Tags: x11, size

I just installed Fedora 19 on a VirtualBox and when I started it for the first time it only allowed the screen resolution 1024x768

After some research I managed to install the guest additions and I got a few more screen sizes but as none of them matched my screen I did some further research and found this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58960/screen-resolution-problem-in-fedora-17-on-oracle-virtualbox-4-2/58966#58966) which showed me how to set the screen. But now I have to do it manually every time I log in. And when I login after setting it manually I get these errors:

```
none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 62
CRTC 62: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1600x1200@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1440x1050@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1280x960@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1600x1200@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1440x1050@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1280x960@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 62: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 62: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
CRTC 62: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1368x768@60Hz (pass 1)
```

I understand that this configuration should be put in the X config file xorg.conf but I cannot find it anywhere on my system (tried /dev/X11 and /dev/X11/xorg.conf.d but there was nothing there.

I also tried `Xorg -configure :0`

But I get this error:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the Fedora Project support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE)
```

So I'm at a dead end and need some help.

Comment: I faced same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. I removed ~/.config/monitors.xml and the error was gone.
Found answer at: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=256312